# How to set Item position in order after using ItemTouchHelper.Callback

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I am creating a document arrangement activity with `RecyclerView`. I want to arrange the document with drag and drop. It was done by using `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`but after that **I can't set the page number after the `OnItemMove` callback.** what should I do?

**EDIT: added code snippet**

```
package adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.mobilix.docscanner.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import helper.ItemTouchHelperAdapter;
import helper.ItemTouchHelperViewHolder;
import helper.OnStartDragListener;
import helper.SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback;

public class PageAjdustAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PageAjdustAdapter.PageAdjustHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter, OnStartDragListener {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<PdfPage> pdfPages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper;

    public PageAjdustAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PdfPage> pages) {
        this.mContext = context;
        pdfPages = pages;


        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(this);
        itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.rcvPageArrange));

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PageAdjustHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_page_adajustment, parent, false);
        return new PageAdjustHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PageAdjustHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: ");
        holder.ivPage.setImageBitmap(pdfPages.get(position).bitmap);
        holder.cbPage.setChecked(pdfPages.get(position).isSelected);
        holder.tvPageNo.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        holder.cbPage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                pdfPages.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).isSelected = isChecked;
            }
        });

        holder.ivRotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                pdfPages.get(pos).bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(//
                        pdfPages.get(pos).bitmap, 0, 0, pdfPages.get(pos).bitmap.getWidth(),//
                        pdfPages.get(pos).bitmap.getHeight(), pdfPages.get(pos).matrix, true);//

                notifyItemChanged(pos);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pdfPages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemMove: ->fp " + (fromPosition + 1) + " tp-> " + (toPosition + 1));
        Collections.swap(pdfPages, fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

        
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        pdfPages.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        itemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder);

    }


    public static class PageAdjustHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        ImageView ivPage, ivRotate;
        CheckBox cbPage;
        TextView tvPageNo;

        public PageAdjustHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivPage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPage);
            ivRotate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivRotate);
            cbPage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbPage);
            tvPageNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPageNo);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {

        }
    }

    public static class PdfPage {
        PdfRenderer.Page page;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        boolean isSelected;
        Matrix matrix;
        int rotate = 0;

        public PdfPage(PdfRenderer.Page page, Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.page = page;
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            matrix = new Matrix();
            rotate += 90;
            matrix.postRotate(90);//martix work on +=90
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet.

Comment: code snippet added.

Comment: "I can't set the page number"? Which page number? Can you elaborate your issue in terms of code instead of what you are seeing on your App

Comment: after onItemMove occurred, I want set position numbers in order for all items.

Comment: Do you mean after arranging the pages, you want the page numbers to be refreshed in sequence but the page numbers are showing as they were prior to arranging the pages of document?

Comment: Yes, I want to refresh page numbers in all items.

Comment: check is your onBindViewHolder is getting called after onItemMoved and let me know your findings

Comment: No,onBindViewHolder not called after onItemMoved .that's why I can't refresh items.

Comment: then you might not be seeing the correct sequence of pages also right? as onBindViewHolder is not called

Comment: Yes,now you got it.

Comment: try calling notifyDataSetChanged once and why are you retuning false from onItemMove, isn't it should be true since you consumed the event?

Comment: already tried, but it throws an exception.

Comment: tried what? notifydataSetChanged or retuning true?

Comment: notifydataSetChanged

Comment: what was the exception? can you poset here. Also what about the retuning value of onItemMoved?

Comment: sorry, it's not throwing an exception, but it will arrange without animation and returning true also not a solution.

Comment: got it! But when you were using notifyDatasetChanged, were your page numbers correct? (if we do not consider animation for a minute)

Comment: yes, at this way, i can set the page number,but only once,after that drag stops working...

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/52286338/8762338

Comment: No,it's not working,only jurking items on drag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242037/discussion-between-eas-and-astha-garg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() when an item position is changed. The easiest way it to used onItemClear(), it will be called when an item is de-selected. Add it like following.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClear() {
          notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

One thing you have to add is check weather the position is actually changed after the drag operation or not other wise it will always update the whole dataset whenever an item is selected and than de-selected.

**Edit**

Create a local variable in view-holder class. Than you just have to set it in onItemSelected() and check it in onItemClear();

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected() {
        lastpos = getAdapterPosition();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClear() {
         if(lastpos != getAdapterPosition())
              notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Great! your answer is correct. but at that time, when we remove item **fromPosition** and add that item at **toPosition** in  `onItemMove()` event with `notifyItemMoved()`.

Comment: See the edit for checking weather item pos is changed or not.